# R from SAS PROC SQL Conditional Join

Tags: r, sas

I'm trying to join two very large tables based off of a conditional statement.  I want to join df2 onto df1 within each group (x), but only include rows from df2 that fall within the min and max values in df2.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3), y = seq(1,10))
df2 <- data.frame(x2 = c(1,1,2,2,2), y_min = c(1, 1, 6, 6, 6), y_max = c(3,3,9,9,9), cat = c("A",'A','S','S','S'))
```

The result I'm looking for is

```
df3 <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3), y = seq(1,10), y_min = c(1,1,1,NA,NA,6,6,6,6,NA), y_max = c(3,3,3,NA,NA,9,9,9,9,NA), cat = c('A','A','A',NA,NA,'S','S','S','S',NA))

   x  y y_min y_max  cat
1  1  1     1     3    A
2  1  2     1     3    A
3  1  3     1     3    A
4  1  4    NA    NA <NA>
5  2  5    NA    NA <NA>
6  2  6     6     9    S
7  2  7     6     9    S
8  2  8     6     9    S
9  2  9     6     9    S
10 3 10    NA    NA <NA>
```

This was originally written in a SAS PROC SQL script, but am having trouble converting it to R.  The PROC SQL statement looked something like...

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN tbl2 b
   on (a.col1 - b.col1) >= 0 and (a.col1 - b.col2) <= 0
     and a.id = b.id
```

I've tried using base:: & data.table::merge, but am not having any luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package `sqldf` to use `SQL` code on `R` objects. As a side note your SAS names were different that the names you used in R, for future reference make sure they are the same so people can reproduce.

```
library(sqldf)
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3), y = seq(1,10))
df2 <- data.frame(x2 = c(1,1,2,2,2), y_min = c(1, 1, 6, 6, 6), y_max = c(3,3,9,9,9), cat = c("A",'A','S','S','S'))

sqldf('SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM df1 a
LEFT JOIN df2 b
   on (a.y - b.y_min) >= 0 and (a.y- b.y_max) <= 0
     and a.x = b.x2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

unique(df2)[df1,
            .(x = i.x, y = i.y, y_min = x.y_min, y_max = x.y_max, cat = x.cat),
            on = c("x2 == x", "y_min <= y", "y_max >= y")]

    x  y y_min y_max  cat
 1: 1  1     1     3    A
 2: 1  2     1     3    A
 3: 1  3     1     3    A
 4: 1  4    NA    NA <NA>
 5: 2  5    NA    NA <NA>
 6: 2  6     6     9    S
 7: 2  7     6     9    S
 8: 2  8     6     9    S
 9: 2  9     6     9    S
10: 3 10    NA    NA <NA>
```

Just a note - there were duplicate rows in `df2` resulting in a simple left join yielding more rows than you indicated in `df3`, hence the call to `unique()`.

Comment: What does the i used for? in i.x & i.y?

Comment: the prefix `i.` in the `j` argument to a `data.table` refers to columns of `i` when `i` is a data.table (as is the case here). If you're particularly curious, check out `?data.table` and give it a read-through. There's a lot but it's very helpful.

Comment: Ah got ya makes sense!  Do you need the j part if I just want to join and keep all columns?

Comment: By default it would just keep the columns from `X` (`df1` in our case), I believe. You can check it out, though.